# Service Fabric - can a .net 4.7.2 application running in a container on IIS access the fabric configuration settings?

Tags: containers, azure-service-fabric

I have a Fabric application that I need to deploy a SSRS report viewer control to. The control is webforms, and there is no .net core version available yet, so my plan is to host it in a windows container with IIS.

I would like to keep all my configuration in one place, that place being the service fabric manifests. Will it be possible for the webforms pages to read fabric configuration from inside of the container?

when I attempt to get config from fabric I get this error

```
Unable to load DLL 'FabricRuntime.dll':
```

I have tried to call SfBinaryLoader as is detailed below, but no change

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-services-inside-containers

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

1. Load config via the SF APIs, which is what you are trying to do or
2. Load config just via reading the file. Some folders are automatically mounted inside the container, which you can access through the file system in the container for example using the Fabric_Folder_Application environment variable (or [others](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-environment-variables-reference) depending on where exactly you're keeping your config), or mounting the config path via a volume:

```
<Volume Source="/mnt/hostfolder/" Destination="/var/containerfolder/" IsReadOnly="false" />
```

Using the SF APIs from within the container is possible. I would recommend following the guide that you pointed to separately and to ask separate questions if you cannot get that to work as it may help identify other issues.

That said, using the APIs is less common for containerized workloads. Normally people just use [Environment Variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-how-to-specify-environment-variables) to configure services running within Containers, as that is more common/standard, even if less flexible.